# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have an ASP.NET MVC web site and a WCF service.

We use Windows authentication on the web site and want to pass the credentials from the website to the service. Usually (so far) the service and the web site are on the same server. At the moment we pass the username as a string but are aware this is probably not a good option.

We want to know the AD username when the WCF service method is executed as we have mappings in our database that maps AD users to various roles in our system.

We want the WCF service to run as the IIS identity that we configured it with as this user has access to SQL.

Where do we go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Forms Authentication Ticket](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) to pass along the user name. Make sure you override the encryption and domain if the WCF and the MVC will be on different boxes/domains. Those instructions mention the machineKey, but for the domain it is just a `domain="MyDomain"` attribute in the forms element.

Comment: so no way to have the service know the actual AD user identity?

Comment: @AranMulholland not sure about that, but this is what we used to pass along the user name between WCF and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state what binding you were using.  If you use something like this, it should work:

```
    <binding name="IWABinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

You'd probably use it with a netTcpBinding.  You can also use it over basicHttpBinding and you can also consider TransportCredentialOnly.

For more info, see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)